# How to reuse WebRTC socket when the page reload?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, voip, webrtc

I'm using WebRTC JS to create peer-to-peer voice calls.

The problem is that once I close the window (which includes WebRTC lib) I lose the session. The lib has to load whenever a user loads a new page. This can have terrible implications on performance.

WebRTC uses websockets, and the site uses http requests for navigation so pages reload when a user navigates, this closes the websocket and hence the call.

I don't want to use iframe or use SPA with Ajax calls. Is there anyway we can reuse the TCP socket when the page reload?

Comment: Reuse the Peer2Peer connection socket or the signalling server socket?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @BenjaminTren. I think i'm more interested with sharing the signalling socket and reuses it.

Comment: Closing the websockets do not close the call. Destroying the peer connection object does that(which is done on refresh)

Comment: Ya sorry, I'm interested of finding a way to maintain the call if I refresh the page, so it's the peer connection. Is there anyway to keep the peer connection when I refresh the page?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, the state of the WebRTC API provided by the browser is destroyed on a page refresh and I doubt that there is a way to save it. You may be able to save the information given in a successful call(the SDP and such) but I am not sure that you can set and create those manually and it be successful.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminTrent, very helpful.I think the best work around would be trying to use Ajax/SPA extensively to make sure the user stay at the same page without refreshing it.